# Add rotateY(36deg) every 5 Sec in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]I have one problem that is was how to add rotateY(36deg) every 5 sec.
like:- 36deg after 5 sec it will become 72deg like so on

this is link:-
but there is no autoplay option.
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Minimal-3D-Perspective-Carousel-with-jQuery-CSS3-3D-Carousel/

Comment: Hard to see without your code, but SetInterval might help you achieve this....https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Come out code don't be shy code. aww Forget it this code too shy to show

Comment: You could use a pure css solution too

Answer (score 1):

this is some css approach with jquery see on [link FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/jmtn1e56/3/) 
and this is code snippet 
also u can add animation by searching little bit more

```js
var a = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(function() {
     a=a+36;
     console.log(a);
     $('.numcountbyinterval').text(a);
     $('.rotate').css({ 'transform': 'rotateY(' + a + 'deg)'});
     }, 500);
});
```

```css
.rotate{
  background-color:#ccc;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="numcountbyinterval">0</span>
<div class="rotate">
Box inside wow
</div>
```

Comment: I share the link, please have a look

Comment: can you atleast show some code of that plugin you tried to use until now ? @BharatNegi

Answer (score 0):

I set 500ms for the faster effect. Change `500` into `5000` to get 5sec and also remove `perspective` and `perspective-origin` css properties if you prefer 2d effect.

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');
var time = 5000;
var degPerTime = 36;
var framesPersecond = 32;
var intervalTime = 1000/degPerTime;
var degPerInterval = (degPerTime*intervalTime)/time

var rotate = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
  rotate -= degPerInterval;
  box.style.transform = 'translateZ(-385px) rotateY('+rotate+'deg)';
},intervalTime);
```

```css
body{
  perspective: 500px;
  perspective-origin: 10% 10%;
}

#box{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#33aaff;
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;

}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but i have add class on div and my css is:- 

1.Step:- transform: translateZ(-385px) rotateY(0deg);
2.Step:- transform: translateZ(-385px) rotateY(-36deg);
3.Step:- transform: translateZ(-385px) rotateY(-72deg);
4.Step:- transform: translateZ(-385px) rotateY(-108deg);

and go add not go back to zero

Comment: if `translateZ` is static, just add this to the `box.style.transform` string. I've edited the code to get the smooth move also. It rotates 36deg in 5sec

Comment: i add the image, so you clear the idea, left right arrow is also working and you first code is fine but when i click on left arrow that is not count current position of deg which you add dynamic